# How to access JSON data in classic ASP using json2.asp or aspjson libraries?

Tags: json, asp-classic

Using http://www.aspjson.com/ or https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution/blob/master/lib/axe/classes/Parsers/json2.asp object I managed to get my data from URL to the dictionary object. But I tried and can not think of the way to get the data from the "opening" object using aspjson :-( I have not managed to find a way to get any data using json2.asp library. Here is my data:

```
{
"restaurant": {
    "id": 6,
    "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "visiblemail": "1",
    "date": "2014-07-24 07:38:59",
    "logo": "818_294.png",
    "img": "818_554|818_558|818_563",
    "opening": {
        "sun": [
            "closed"
        ],
        "mon": [
            "10.00",
            "20.00"
        ],
        "tue": [
            "10.00",
            "20.00"
        ],
        "wed": [
            "10.00",
            "20.00"
        ],
        "thu": [
            "10.00",
            "20.00"
        ],
        "fri": [
            "10.00",
            "20.00"
        ],
        "sat": [
            "closed"
        ],
        "hol": [
            "zaprto"
        ]
    },

    "timetable": null
}
```

}

I know both libraries use dictionary object to store the data, but I am lost how do I retrieve the data from the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `isObject` check to see if the element has inner members.

The include file used is from the link you gave

```vb
<!--#include file="aspJSON1.17.asp" -->
<%
Set oJSON = New aspJSON
jsonstring = "{ "&_
"""restaurant"": {"&_
    """id"": 6,"&_
    """email"": ""xyz@gmail.com"","&_
    """visiblemail"": ""1"","&_
    """date"": ""2014-07-24 07:38:59"","&_
    """logo"": ""818_294.png"","&_
    """img"": ""818_554|818_558|818_563"","&_
    """opening"": {"&_
    "    ""sun"": ["&_
    "        ""closed"""&_
    "    ],"&_
    "    ""mon"": ["&_
    "        ""10.00"","&_
    "        ""20.00"""&_
    "    ],"&_
    "    ""tue"": ["&_
    "        ""10.00"","&_
    "        ""20.00"""&_
    "    ],"&_
    "    ""wed"": ["&_
    "        ""10.00"","&_
    "        ""20.00"""&_
    "    ],"&_
    "    ""thu"": ["&_
    "        ""10.00"","&_
    "        ""20.00"""&_
    "    ],"&_
    "    ""fri"": ["&_
    "        ""10.00"","&_
    "        ""20.00"""&_
    "    ],"&_
    "    ""sat"": ["&_
    "        ""closed"""&_
    "    ],"&_
    "    ""hol"": ["&_
    "        ""zaprto"""&_
    "    ]"&_
    "},"&_
    """timetable"": null"&_
"}"


'Load JSON string
oJSON.loadJSON(jsonstring)

set restaurant = oJSON.data("restaurant")

for each itm in restaurant
    if Not IsObject(restaurant.item(itm)) then
        Response.write itm  &" : "& restaurant.item(itm) & "<br/>"
    else
    'opening
        for each dayy in restaurant.item(itm)
            Response.write dayy & ":"
                Response.write restaurant.item(itm)(dayy)(0) 

                If restaurant.item(itm)(dayy)(1) <> "" Then
                    Response.write " - "
                    Response.write restaurant.item(itm)(dayy)(1) 
                End If

            Response.write "<br/>"
        next
    end if

    
next




%>
```

Using the file at:https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution/blob/master/lib/axe/classes/Parsers/json2.asp
You can traverse through the json using the `.enumerate()` call, which returns all keys in a name-value collection and indexes in an array.

```
<%

Sub Traverse(oJson)
    Dim key

    For Each key In oJson.enumerate()
        
        If IsObject(oJson.get(key)) Then
            Response.write key & " => " 
            Traverse oJson.get(key) 'Recursive call
        Else
            Response.Write(key & "=" & oJson.get(key) & "<br/>")
        End If
    Next

End Sub

%>
```

Call it like:

```
set oJSON= json.parse(jsonstring)
Traverse oJSON
```

Comment: Works great, that is what I needed, I couldn't figure that out how to iterate through nested objects :-(