# How do you retrieve a JSON property from an array in aspJSON?

Tags: arrays, json, vbscript, asp-classic

```vb
testdata =
"{payments:
  [{'status': 'succeeded', 
    'in_store_payment_type': None, 
    'refunds': [], 
    'created_at': '2021-10-20T17:23:41-0400', 
    'amount_paid_display': '53.00', 
    'initial_amount_paid_display': '53.00', 
    'currency': 'usd', 
    'initial_amount_paid': 5300, 
    'pk': 75552720, 
    'type': 'affiliate', 
    'amount_paid': 5300
  }]
}"
```

I have tried:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>  
<!--#include file="aspJSON.asp" -->
<%
(read testdata....)

set oJSON= json.parse(testdata)

response.write "Data->" & oJSON.payments.get(0).status
%>
```

Had hoped to see "succeeded" but no luck.
any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access JSON data in classic ASP using json2.asp or aspjson libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24974362) (seen as though you've deleted the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69981270/get-data-from-a-json-array-using-classic-asp-i-have-json2-asp-and-or-aspjson-a)).

Comment: Well, I think it  does BUT, I could not get it to work with my data

Comment: The sample you've provided doesn't look like the correct syntax for Classic ASP, the `#include` isn't structured properly and the VBScript should be contained within `<% ... %>` ASP preprocessor tags. This would never run, you must be getting an error could you actually [edit] the question and post what the error is or a runnable sample at least?

Comment: That data you've provided isn't JSON. You'll have to parse it manually.

Comment: Single quotes (`'`) for identifiers is not valid in a JSON object, you should use double quotes (`"`). See [Introducing JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues with this script, not a fan of the [aspJSON library](https://github.com/gerritvankuipers/aspjson) personally but this should get you started (change the `#include` location to suit your environment).

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>
<% Option Explicit %>
<!-- #include virtual = "/scripts/aspJSON1.19.asp" -->
<%
Dim testdata: testdata = _
  "{""payments"" :" & _
  "  [{""status"": ""succeeded""," & _
  "   ""in_store_payment_type"": None," & _ 
  "   ""refunds"": []," & _
  "   ""created_at"": ""2021-10-20T17:23:41-0400""," & _
  "   ""amount_paid_display"": ""53.00""," & _
  "   ""initial_amount_paid_display"": ""53.00""," & _
  "   ""currency"": ""usd""," & _
  "   ""initial_amount_paid"": 5300," & _
  "   ""pk"": 75552720," & _
  "   ""type"": ""affiliate""," & _
  "   ""amount_paid"": 5300" & _
  " }]" & _
  "}"

Dim oJSON: Set oJSON = New aspJSON
Call oJSON.loadJSON(testdata)
Dim payment
For Each payment In oJSON.data("payments")
  Dim this: Set this = oJSON.data("payments")(payment)
  response.write "Data->" & this.item("status")
Next
%>
```

Output:

```
Data->succeeded
```

#### A couple of key points

- JSON needs to use double quotes (`"`) not single quotes (`'`) for it's identifiers. Ref [Introducing JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)
- The aspJSON library does not support the `parse()` method, instead you use `loadJSON()`.
- You need to enumerate the `payments` collection using a `For` statement to access properties inside the enumerated object.

---

#### Useful Links

- [Looping though JSON classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48271545/692942)
- [Any good libraries for parsing JSON in Classic ASP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1019223/692942)
- [How to access JSON data in classic ASP using json2.asp or aspjson libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979887/692942)