# ASP JSON Accessing key and value in loop

Tags: json, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm using ASPJSON (https://www.aspjson.com/) to write JSON in Classic ASP / VBScript. I'm then attempting to loop through the JSON and access both the key and value. As it stands I can only access the value.

JSON

```
Set InitialGlaDataJsonForm = New aspJSON
With InitialGlaDataJsonForm.data

    .Add "glaFormContent", InitialGlaDataJsonForm.Collection() 
    With .item("glaFormContent")

        .Add "form", "myform"
        .Add "email", "email@address"
        .Add "phone", "012345"
        .Add "name", "Joe Bloggs"

    End With

End With
```

JSON Looks like this

```
{
    "glaFormContent": {
        "form": "myform",
        "email": "email@address",
        "phone": "012345",
        "name": "Joe Bloggs"
    }
}
```

Looping through the JSON, accessing the value

```
For Each element In InitialGlaDataJsonForm.data("glaFormContent")
     response.write InitialGlaDataJsonForm.data("glaFormContent").item(element) & "<br>"
Next
```

The above returns the value of during each iteration, however I need to be able to get hold of the key, without writing it out.

So my question is how do I access the key in the same manner as the value?

Many thanks

Comment: `Response.Write element` will give you the key. In ASPJSON when looping through the `data` dictionary, `element` is your key and `.item(element)` gives you the value related to that key.

Comment: Related - [How do you retrieve a JSON property from an array in aspJSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70027129)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating the dictionary collection using a `For` statement the enumerator used by ASPJSON is the "key", in your case the variable `element`. If you use;

```
Response.Write element
```

the current key will be returned, you can then use;

```
Response.Write InitialGlaDataJsonForm.data("glaFormContent").item(element)
```

to retrieve the underlying value associated with the key.

---

#### Useful Links

- [Answer to How do you retrieve a JSON property from an array in aspJSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70027129/692942)